# generate a graphic with javafx outside of application class?

Tags: java, javafx

I really like the way javafx is set up for rendering 2D graphics and I've built a whole class around making a chart with it. I've been able to successfully have this create a png of the `Pane` object so I can save it locally and display it later.

The problem I'm having is when I want to use my drawing class outside of a class which extends the JavaFX `Application` (to be more specific I want to make this a part of a library, where the library supports outputting a png of the rendered graphic. But as a library it doesn't seem efficient to create a UI.)

### Things that work:

- Building the drawing object (makes the pane, does the initial graphic work, no errors).
- Calling class methods that add `Arc`s to the graphic pane.

### Things that break:

- Calling class method that adds text to the pane (fails on `new Text("")` declaration). Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal graphics not initialized yet
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getScreens(Screen.java:70)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getMainScreen(Screen.java:61)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontFactory.getSystemFontSize(PrismFontFactory.java:1876)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.getSystemFontSize(PrismFontLoader.java:241)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.getDefaultSystemFontSize(Font.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.text.Font.getDefault(Font.java:86)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getFont(Text.java:478)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getFontInternal(Text.java:487)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getTextLayout(Text.java:226)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.needsFullTextLayout(Text.java:184)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.access$200(Text.java:95)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$2.invalidated(Text.java:389)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.setText(Text.java:370)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.<init>(Text.java:129)
    at io.dreadylocks.astrojava.drawing.ChartDraw.addPlanets(ChartDraw.java:211)
    at io.dreadylocks.astrojava.Chart.generateChartImage(Chart.java:192)
    at io.dreadylocks.astrojava.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:15)
```

- Calling class method that saves to png (fails on `WritableImage image = chart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);`). Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:444)
    at javafx.scene.Node.snapshot(Node.java:1928)
    at io.dreadylocks.astrojava.drawing.ChartDraw.toPng(ChartDraw.java:220)
    at io.dreadylocks.astrojava.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:15)
```

All of these class methods can be called after the object creation when I create the object in the `start()` method of a class that extends `Application`. But not otherwise.

If I in fact, *have to* do the image generation inside an Application class, how exactly does that work? I make an instance of the class, but it needs to be run somehow...?

Comment: It's not about the `Application` class. The `RuntimeException` is saying you need to make sure the JavaFX toolkit is initialized before you can utilize its graphics system. There are at least three ways to start JavaFX: (1) `Application.launch(...)`, (2) `Platform.startup(() -> ...)`, and (3) `new JFXPanel()`. Your `IllegalStateException` is different; it's saying the toolkit is initialized but you're on the wrong thread. You can schedule actions on the FX thread with `Platform.runLater(() -> ...)`.

Comment: @Slaw I did try using `Application.launch()` but I can't seem to pass in my object that has all the data I need to render the final graphic. Can you point me at any resources on how I might use the second two methods with javaFX? My google fu is failing me on finding good examples. Thanks!

Comment: First, what is your actual goal? Is this an application with a UI that the user interacts with? Or are you trying to create an application that renders graphics "invisibly".

Comment: @abg For your purpose the Platform.startup(() -> ...) variant is probably the more relevant one, but don't forget that you can call that only once. After the first call you have to use Platform.runLater(() -> ...) instead.

Comment: @Slaw I'm trying to make a library/API, the primary part is the calculations it does, but as a secondary feature I want graphical output of the data so rendering "invisibly" is accurate to what I want. I will need to be able to pass the information that gets generated into the javafx application, too. That seems to be where I run into the most trouble.

Comment: @mipa will calling `Platform.runLater(()->...)` after `Platform.startup(()->...)` continue to access the same instance of the application so I can make calls to objects in it?

Comment: Then the first time you need to access the graphics system you should call `Platform.startup(Runnable)`. The given `Runnable` will be invoked on the _JavaFX Application Thread_ once the toolkit is initialized. Afterwards, you would call `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` whenever you need to pass an action to the FX thread (if not already on the FX thread). And there can only be one JavaFX application per JVM instance.